# Easy-to-use web CMS that supports A/B testing and has built-in user analytics?

Tags: cms, analytics

I'm finding that Google Analytics is not perfect:

- In a highly javascript-enabled site it seems to miss a ton of events
- I'd love to not screw around with manual [A/B testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A/B_testing) and have this whole thing be somewhat solutioned out in one piece of software. My goal is to A/B test certain landing pages and key elements on the home page and track conversions based on those tests... nothing fancy.

Appreciate any input

Comment: Do you mean a web content management system, a tool that let's you create/manage a website? CMS has many meanings: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMS#Computing

Comment: sorry, yes.. a web content management system

Answer (score 2):

We use KISSmetrics. We still have Google Analytics serve up the test but use KISSmetrics to fire events and properties. Properties are tied to the user and let us know what version they experienced.